# missing ) after argument list, instead saw `'squares'

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try this code I get the above error message. JSLint returns: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 1 and instead saw 'squares'.

I don't know why or where a ) should go.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var squares =$('<div class='squares'></div>');
    for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
        squares.appendTo('#container');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes properly

```
 var squares = $("<div class='squares'></div>");
```

instead of

```
 var squares =$('<div class='squares'></div>');
```